# Does return-path email address domain have a deliverability reputation?

Tags: email

Just wondering if I should build my delivery reputation over return-path email address domain (by keeping it same in every campaign delivery) or can I change it regularly?

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by changing? Local part, domain part or both?

Answer (score 2):

On my systems not. On others surely. But on others maybe not. Who cares?!

Deliverability is way too localized to be answered by "yes" or "no". You should probably better look at other top10 deliverability tips than this one.

Comment: Agreed, though one thought is that some systems will check SPF for `envelope from` and header `from`, `reply-to`, and `sender`. My personal system checks the first three of that. At work we only check the envelope from. As you said, everyone does something different.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. Return-Path have **nothing** common with **any** reputation

Comment: Says who? Any reference? How do you know how I handle this on my mail server?

Comment: Agree! Do you have any reference to your answer? Just wondering if return-path is only important for tracking bounces or have affect on delivery reputation as well (not mentioning about SPF, wondering about reputation).

Comment: RFC 2821 (**stanadards track**) p 4.4 states requirements to return-path field and it's usage. NDR-address just used *as expected*, where reputation was hidden here I can't imagine